# Shopify POST Request going to Continue URL

Tags: php, json, api, postman, shopify

I tried to make a post request in Postman (and in PHP) to a url to create a fulfillments, but for some reason, Shopify displays a link stating continue which points me to logging into Shopify.

I looked up the issue and this issue commonly seems to be attributed to cookies, but I disabled cookies and still have this same problem. I also tried with my local PC in docker and I assume the same issue persists.

[image: Postman screen showing Continue link as a response to a POST call to Shopify]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Click the **Cookies** button right below the request bar:

[image]

2. Remove cookies related to your Shopify store.
3. Send request again.

Comment: I found my issue, I had an extra # in my URL.

Comment: Thanks this help me as I'm using different stores in my postman, I've delete the existing cookies then it worked on the POST request.